# Vuetify - Outline color set programatically

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Does anyone know how to programatically set the outline color on a `v-text-field` ?

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
<v-text-field v-model="value" :class="value === 0 ? greenStyle : regularStyle"/>

<style>
  .greenStyle {
    color: green
  },

  .redStyle {}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use color attribute like this **:** `:color="!value ? 'green' : 'red'"`

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
     value: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-container>
            <v-text-field
              label="Outlined"
              outlined
              v-model="value"
              :color="value === '0' ? 'green' : 'red'"
            ></v-text-field>
      </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I thought, it's not working for me :/

Comment: What issue you are facing ? It's straight forward

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7x5twyfj/2/
Here I copy pasted your code and it doesnt work

Comment: It only colors red while the cursor is inside the text field

Comment: @isebarn Why downvoted ? Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that. You can check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/svpgbj18/

Comment: "It only colors red while the cursor is inside the text field"
I am trying to make the outline permanently green/red. Now it only works if the cursor is placed inside the element

Comment: Yup, the default behavior of vuetify text field is to color them only when the input is selected. If you want to color them even if they aren't selected you might need to use some custom css to override vuetify styles.